# Compiling an old compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile an old gcc cross compiler (2.95) with a newer compiler (3.4.6). My host is --host=i386-redhat-linux. and I am getting the next assembler error message during the unwind-dw2.c :

```
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:259: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r11,low(r0,.L47),r11'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:736: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L327),r3'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:1226: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L317),r3'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:1739: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L412),r3'
```

can anybody explain why my compiler is creating this assembly instructions ?

**UPDATE :**
this error are created while **xgcc** is compiling this file... apparently there is a stage when building the cross compiler that **xgcc** is compiling things ... what is this **xgcc** !? and why it create invalid assembly code ? need help ...

Comment: I'm guessing that you need the whole set of the old coreutils.

Comment: Are you getting this message when compiling the compiler or when using the compiled compiler?

Comment: when compiling the compiler...that what makes it weird...because the gcc tools should be sync with each other... it like the compiler isn't sync with the assembler tool...could anybody know how I can check that their version is Ok for working with each other (the compiler and the assemebler) ?

Comment: The old compiler source could have inline assembler that is not compatible with the newer assembly.

Comment: So how can I install much older compiler ? The one that came with the OS is apparently not good... I know that I can download the source and build it but I already tried doing that with any luck (tried to build 3.0.3)... :(